# Center text vertically inside an already vertically centered div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm broken down on struggle street. What I'm trying to do is vertically center text that is inside an already centered div using css3 transform. I have tried so many different methods and have had zero luck. I don't want to just add padding to the top of the text, is there any other way? The div height will also change because it is responsive.

[Play my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gx25ospo/15/)

Heres my code-

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.intro {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #83fec6;
  color: #3a58e9;
}
.intro .container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<section class="intro">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300&text=CHUMP">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
        <h1>CENTER ME VERTICALLY<br>OH YEAH</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I think you want like: https://jsfiddle.net/gx25ospo/13/ ?

Comment: This aint no dupe brozef